# crontab not working with date entry

Tags: cron, freebsd

Can anyone let me know why this does not work:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.oYrOhTNQ48 installed on Wed Feb 19 17:10:46 2014)
# (Cron version -- $FreeBSD: src/usr.sbin/cron/crontab/crontab.c,v 1.22.2.1.6.1 2008/10/02 02:57:24 kensmith Exp $)
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/home/dennis/bin
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/tcsh
TZ=GMT

## backup
0 */4 * * * /usr/local/mysql-5.1.50/bin/mysqldump -e -u username -ppassword sm | /usr/bin/gzip > /tmp/database.`date +%m-%d-%Y-%T`.sql.gz
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /usr/home/dennis/thisworks
* * * * * env > ~/env.output
```

Unfortunately I have no access to the log files.. so I can't see any errors. manually it works fine.  If I take out the `date +%m-%d-%Y-%T` it works too.  I even tried full path to date with no luck.

A little help?

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) Is this the `crontab` for your user account? (2) why is your file showing the "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE" line? This shouldn't happen if you're editing it properly with `crontab -e`, and (3) by "does not work" what are the symptoms? Is there no output file at all in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the very same problem and finally fixed it by escaping the % characters in the date command.

The line in crontab should remain the same, just change:

```
`date +%m-%d-%Y-%T`
```

to

```
`date +\%m-\%d-\%Y-\%T`
```

As mentioned before, you should *never* edit the system crontab file. You should use instead:

```
crontab -e
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have shell access ?

Best way to just run

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.50/bin/mysqldump -e -u username -ppassword sm | /usr/bin/gzip > /tmp/database.`date +%m-%d-%Y-%T`.sql.gz
```

in shell. you will then see whatever the error is.

Once the bash command is working then move it to cron and just apply the date setting.

Answer (score 0):

For me works doing this:

First set you password and DBDescription to a encrypted file with this command bellow:
    mysql_config_editor set --login-path=DBDescription --host=DB#.pair.com --user=DBUser --port=3306 --password

See if that works:
    mysql_config_editor print --login-path=DBDescription

The output will be something like this:

```
[DBDescription]
user = root
password = *****
host = localhost
port = 3306
```

Now create a shell script:

```
​#!/bin/sh
#Set paths
MYDUMP=/usr/local/bin/mysqldump
BACKUPDIR=/usr/local/www/apache24/data
MYGZIP=/usr/bin/gzip
MYFIND=/usr/bin/find
#Dump
$MYDUMP --login-path=DBDescription DBNAME > $BACKUPDIR/mysql-DBNAME.`date '+%d-%B-%Y--%Hh'`.sql
#GZIP the file
$MYGZIP $BACKUPDIR/mysql-DBNAME.`date '+%d-%B-%Y--%Hh'`.sql
```

And finally create a job with cron.
Here I use:

```
# nano /etc/crontab
```

At the final line of the file add:

```
00 04 * * * root /usr/local/www/apache24/data/mybackup.sh
```

Based on the information of this: [link.](https://www.pair.com/support/kb/set-automated-database-backups-freebsd/)